# What rulings and fiqh views are there for prayers and wudu' with bandage?

Tags: salat, fiqh, wudu, medical

Years ago I had a [Scaphoid fracture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaphoid_fracture) and before consulting a physician I made wudu' and later got a cast. According what I researched at the time the maliki school of fiqh considers praying with this cast or bandages that couldn't or shouldn't be taken off as walid if I wipped on it with water, if one has been tahir when getting it.
A friend of mine who is shafi'i told me that in their madhhab this isn't sufficient and I should re-do all the prayers once the cast was taken off. This would have meant around 6 months of prayers in my case as I most of my hand, my forearm and most of my upper arm were under that cast which sounds like hardship to me!

I'm curious of what other schools of jurisprudence say or actually what schools of jurisprudence say on the case of bandages and casts on the topic of taharah (wudu') and prayer. Please consider answering by quoting the school of fiqh represented and some of their sources.

Comment: Salamu 'aleikum. I hope you had an enjoyable 'eid el adha. In regard to your question I would never have thought it would be an issue in other schools of thaught. It's just something to protect oneself against viruses and microbes so one can heal properly.